Is there a WordPress plugin or solution that allows to set up forms with a total control over markup
I’m using a Bedrock and Sage stack to develop WordPress site with Blade and Tailwind, and I’m looking for a plugin or a solution to implement forms with a full control over the markup.
I would like to find a solution that can integrate into my workflow and allow me to customize the code, while allowing users to build all the forms they want in the admin.
I’ve tested several solution like Gravity Forms, Ninja Forms, Contact Form 7 and some others top ranked plugins, and they don’t fit my needs.
They’re either too complex, with tons of extra codes and layers, or too simple and lack of customization abilities.
What do you use to provide forms capabilities to your stack?

Have you tried HTML Forms Plugin https://htmlformsplugin.com/ ?

You could do this with Gravity I'd think? You'd just have to make custom form elements with your own HTML where you don't like the default. And I expect all the other plugins are the same. What sort of things don't you like about the generated HTML from these plugins, what do you want to change?

Thanks both! I tested HTML Forms plugin coupled with Sage HTML Forms and it fits my needs.

The tricky thing is that most form plugins are made specifically to control the HTML generation. So, it's gonna be pretty rare to say, "have total control" over the output and also use a visual form builder.
That said, like was mentioned previously, Gravity Forms (and I'm sure others) have pretty extensive PHP APIs for extending the available form elements and behaviors. It can be pretty labor-intensive, and not always very clear from the docs how to do certain things, though.
One option you might want to look at is using a PHP form builder library. If you're comfortable with having to build the forms as part of the development process (instead of having Dashboard users create them), then something like Formr may give you more of the control you're looking for. I was able to get a fairly custom form up and running within an hour of starting the docs.
